# NetworkActivity Icon on stuatus bar during default screen (splash screen)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If I try to insert

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

In the `ViewDidLoad` method it doesn't appears during the splash screen. How can I implement the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the initial splash screen (launch image) that you provide in the project properties: there is nothing you can do there yet, as your application is being loaded and not yet run.

The most early part where you could run your own code is in the `main` method although most functions will not work there as nothing is initialized yet. The earliest code point that is useful for this kind is `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` in your application delegate.

In any case you should review if showing the network indicator is the right thing as it should only be shown when your code is doing network access.